# Bootstrap make div one by one in small screen

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

Hi I am using bootstrap css library 5.1.3, I want to design a simple card which left side image and right side text. It's working perfect in large size screen. But I don't know how to make image first and text contents second at the bottom of the image. Could you please help me to fix it. If it's not fixable by current code then please suggest me any other way to achieve this card design?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
        <title>Test</title>
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">  
      </head>
<body>
    <div class="container py-4">
        <div class="bg-light d-flex"> 
            <div class="flex-shrink-0">
                <img src="https://i.ibb.co/kDv9tyc/img.jpg" height="350">
            </div>
              
            <div class="flex-grow-1 px-3">
                <h1>Title</h1>
                <h2>SubText</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Cupiditate in fugit aspernatur perferendis repudiandae accusantium illum autem hic numquam, non optio tempore, omnis, exercitationem quidem atque iusto mollitia deleniti. Eos minima numquam rem quis ullam quam repudiandae, voluptatibus temporibus dolorem quidem? In cumque exercitationem dicta fugit ipsum facilis quaerat consequuntur eligendi a culpa cum sed ab, magni earum voluptatem? Id et velit enim reiciendis doloribus veniam distinctio alias mollitia, repellendus quisquam ab eos incidunt corrupti earum quidem laudantium quae suscipit.</p>
            </div> 
       </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Output on large size screen:**

[image]

**Current output on small size screen:**

[image]

**Expected output:**

[image]

Comment: Use row and cols, thats the easiest.. add row class to bg-light and col classes to flex shrink and grow div.. 'col-12 col-md-6' for instance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to use bootstrap's flex grid. You create a row with two columns and make them responsive like this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
        <title>Test</title>
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">  
      </head>
<body>
    <div class="container py-4">
        <div class="bg-light row"> 
            <div class="col-md-3 p-3">
                <img src="https://i.ibb.co/kDv9tyc/img.jpg" class="my-image text-center img-fluid">
            </div>
              
            <div class="col-md-9 p-3">
                <h1>Title</h1>
                <h2>SubText</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Cupiditate in fugit aspernatur perferendis repudiandae accusantium illum autem hic numquam, non optio tempore, omnis, exercitationem quidem atque iusto mollitia deleniti. Eos minima numquam rem quis ullam quam repudiandae, voluptatibus temporibus dolorem quidem? In cumque exercitationem dicta fugit ipsum facilis quaerat consequuntur eligendi a culpa cum sed ab, magni earum voluptatem? Id et velit enim reiciendis doloribus veniam distinctio alias mollitia, repellendus quisquam ab eos incidunt corrupti earum quidem laudantium quae suscipit.</p>
            </div> 
       </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**
You want to move the `height` from the front the `html` file, to the `CSS` file. This media query says, for all screens `768px` or higher, make the height of the image `350px`.

Also make the width 100% for the image.

```
img.my-image{
      width:100%
  }
/* // Medium devices (tablets, 768px and up) */
  @media (min-width: 768px) { 
   img.my-image{
     height:350px;
   
    }
 }
```

See the code pen below:

https://codepen.io/shingai/pen/vYpbdKB

Comment: Thank you. It's shows only horizontal card. I want to make it portrait on small size devices. Can you please check the expected output in the question?

Comment: @iDeveloper check out the updated answer and codepen.

Answer (score 1):

Sicne you're using bootstrap, I believe you should be using [Bootstrap grid system](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/layout/grid/), which would turn it into something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
        <title>Test</title>
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">  
      </head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="bg-light row"> 
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <img class="w-100" src="https://i.ibb.co/kDv9tyc/img.jpg">
            </div>
              
            <div class="col-md-9">
                <h1>Title</h1>
                <h2>SubText</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Cupiditate in fugit aspernatur perferendis repudiandae accusantium illum autem hic numquam, non optio tempore, omnis, exercitationem quidem atque iusto mollitia deleniti. Eos minima numquam rem quis ullam quam repudiandae, voluptatibus temporibus dolorem quidem? In cumque exercitationem dicta fugit ipsum facilis quaerat consequuntur eligendi a culpa cum sed ab, magni earum voluptatem? Id et velit enim reiciendis doloribus veniam distinctio alias mollitia, repellendus quisquam ab eos incidunt corrupti earum quidem laudantium quae suscipit.</p>
            </div> 
       </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you.  However I want to static height on the image `height=350`. Is there any way to use static height on large screen and full width on small screen?

Comment: You could use a css media query, which allows you to have some styles for specific break point only e.g. small screen.